# PHP file give me error when uploading on server

Tags: php

```
<?php
$con = “mysqli_connect("https://some.com”,”userid”,”password”)”;
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db(“tomcatsp_userID”, $con);

$sql=INSERT INTO ‘SampleTable’ (USERID, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$_POST[USERID]’,’$_POST[PASSWORD]’);

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "1 record added to tags";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

This is my php code i wanted to upload on server. but when i upload on server give me error.

Below is error log please help me to solve such kind of requirement.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<?php $con = mysql_connect("https://173.243.120.204:2083â€
```

Comment: Please remove ios, iphone and obj-c tags. Nothing to do with them.

Comment: You should really remove those login details.

Comment: Also try not use mysql and use mysqli

Comment: Rob i want to insert user id and password to database through this php file.

Comment: Why have you got https:// in front of a mysql connection?

Comment: dowvoter why downvoting me...

Comment: The first thing as the answers bellow show you have not " on your $sql var and those ` can be removed. In fact i recommended you just rewrite this, and use mysqli

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect("address","username","password") or die("cannot connect DB");
mysql_select_db("iglobe") or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="INSERT INTO SampleTable (USERID, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$_POST[USERID]’,’$_POST[PASSWORD]’)";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());;
if(!$sqlselect)
  die('Error: '.mysql_error());
else
  echo "1 record added to tags";
```

Comment: can i write this code in my php file and then uplad on server.

Comment: You Really should not use mysql anymore, use mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Change this line and try.remove https in the hostname

```
$con = mysqli_connect("https://myaddress.com”,”abc”,xyz”);
 to
$con = mysqli_connect("myaddress.com”,”abc”,xyz”);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**

Issue is with this line:

```
$con = mysql_connect("https://myaddress.com”,”abc”,xyz”);
```

You didn't added opening `"` near `xyz”`

Change it like:

```
$con = mysql_connect('myaddress.com','abc','xyz');
```

Check this manual for further details about [mysql_connect](https://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect)

**Issue 2**

Also the following line is also not correct, wrap it in quotes:

```
$sql=INSERT INTO ‘SampleTable’ (USERID, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$_POST[USERID]’,’$_POST[PASSWORD]’);
```

Change that to:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO ‘SampleTable’ (USERID, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$_POST[USERID]’,’$_POST[PASSWORD]’)";
```

Comment: ("https://myaddress.com”,”abc”,xyz”); at this line can i put my server address and server user id and password? na

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("myaddress.com","abc","xyz");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect:'.mysqli_error());
  }

mysqli_select_db("iglobe", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO SampleTable (USERID, PASSWORD) VALUES (".$_POST[USERID].",'".$_POST[PASSWORD]."')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!$result)
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());

echo "1 record added to tags";

mysqli_close($con)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_connect is deprecated as of php 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

- This is the "official" OO way to do it,
- BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.

  ```
   if ($mysqli->connect_error) 
    {
     die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ')'. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
  ```